# How to pass environment variables when executing command as another user?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

As root I did

```
# WWWFOLDER=myproject
# echo $WWWFOLDER
myproject
# su - anothershelluser /bin/bash -c "echo $WWWFOLDER"

#
```

As you can see, I got nothing printed.

I already tried, without success

```
# su - anothershelluser /bin/bash -c "echo ${WWWFOLDER}"

# su - anothershelluser /bin/bash -c 'echo ${WWWFOLDER}'

# su - anothershelluser /bin/bash -c 'echo $WWWFOLDER'
```

### Question

**How can I pass WWWFOLDER into bash command to be executed ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `-` to `su` is explicitly to ask it to wipe the environment and simulate a login.

Just drop the `-`.

Also, in most `su` implementations, what you pass to `-c` is code to pass to the login shell of the target user, so you need to pass it code in the syntax of that shell. If that shell is Bourne-like:

```
# export VAR=value
# su anothershelluser -c 'printf "%s\n" "$VAR"'
value
```

If you need a bash shell to be executed regardless of what the login shell of the target user is (but why would you), you need to construct code in the syntax of the login shell of the target user that will make it run that bash shell.

If it's Bourne-like, that could be:

```
su anothershelluser -c 'exec bash -c '\''printf "%s\n" "$VAR"'\'
```

Using `sudo` instead of `su` would make it easier:

```
sudo -E -u anothershelluser bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$VAR"'
```

(`-E` to preserve the environment; note that `sudo` will not necessarily preserve *all* of the environment).

The zsh shell has builtin support for changing uid/gids by assigning to the UID, EUID, GID, EGID or USERNAME variables. There, it would be just a matter of:

```
(USERNAME=anothershelluser; bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$VAR"')
```

(which would also skip all the extra stuff that su/sudo do like invoking the pam stack, logging, adding extra pty wrapping, etc).

Comment: I resolved removing the `-`, thanks for detailed explanation of all alternatives