# I want to issue "sudo su - <user>" to create a login shell, and pass an environment variable into the new shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

Oracle linux 7.9. Shell is bash.

I log in as user `bob`. From there I `sudo` to user `sam` and do my work. But I want to pass a variable into `sam`'s new login shell.

- So for example, this is what I currently see:

  ```shellsession
  [bob]$ id
  uid=1111(bob) gid=2444(bob) groups=3444(bob)
  [bob]$ export myvar='My Var'
  [bob]$ sudo su - sam
  [sam]$ echo $myvar

  [sam]$
  ```
- What I **want** to see is:

  ```shellsession
  [bob]$ id
  uid=1111(bob) gid=2444(bob) groups=3444(bob)
  [bob]$ export myvar='My Var'
  [bob]$ sudo su - sam
  [sam]$ echo $myvar
  My Var
  [sam]$
  ```
- I've tried these to no avail:

  ```shell
  sudo VAR=tvar su - sam
  sudo su -c "export mvar='My Var'" - sam
  sudo --preserve_env=myvar su - sam
  ```

Can you help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is answered here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/744201/how-to-pass-environment-variables-when-executing-command-as-another-user